# Why is my leap year algorithm not working (Java)?

Tags: java, algorithm, leap-year

Here is what I have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
    int Year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a month (first three letters with the first"
            + " letter uppercase): ");
    String Month = input.next();

    String ThirtyOne = "Jan" + "Mar" + "May" + "Jul" + "Aug" + "Oct" + "Dec";
    String DaysThirtyOne = ThirtyOne.substring(21) + "31";

    String Thirty = "Apr" + "Jun" + "Sep" + "Nov";
    String DaysThirty = Thirty.substring(12) + "30";

    String TwentyEight = "Feb";
    String DaysTwentyEight = TwentyEight.substring(3) + "28";
    String DaysLeapYear = TwentyEight.substring(3) + "29";


    boolean isLeapYear = ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0) && (Year % 400 == 0));

    if (ThirtyOne.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysThirtyOne 
                + " days in it.");
    }
    if (Thirty.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysThirty 
                + " days in it.");
    }
    if(TwentyEight.contains(Month)) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysTwentyEight 
                + " days in it.");
    }
    if (isLeapYear) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysLeapYear 
                + " days in it.");
    }
```

I am new to programming so I wouldn't be surprised if this code looks immature. Anyways, I have the user input a year and a month (first three letters). I created a boolean variable for a leap year that says whatever year the user inputs needs to be divisible by 4, 100, and 400. Then, I created an if statement for if it is a leap year to print out "Feb (whatever year the user inputs) has DaysLeapYear in it." I think I have something wrong with my algorithm because if I were to take out the if statement of TwentyEight and just kept the leap year if statements, the computer doesn't even print out how many days Feb would have if it was a leap year. Again, I think I'm going wrong in the algorithm, but it could be somewhere else and I was hoping for another look at this to see if someone sees something I am not since I am new to this after all.

Comment: "Why isn't my leap year algorithm not working"  -- so it's working, right?

Comment: @Tucker double negative. *facepalm

Comment: `boolean isLeapYear = ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0) && (Year % 400 == 0));` -- by this, 2000 wasn't a leap year

Comment: @khelwood where am I going wrong?

Comment: It should be "divisible by 4 AND NOT divisible by 100 UNLESS divisible by 400" so your boolean should be `(Year % 4 == 0) && ((Year % 100 != 0) || (Year % 400 == 0))`

Comment: Why not use [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: @proulxs Probably because this looks very much like a school assignment. On that note, this is a well-posed question that shows effort to solve the problem, but a misunderstanding of the proper algorithm to use, while asking the right questions. Sure wish more new users would post like this!

Comment: `java.time.Year.of( 2017 ).isLeap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your isLeapYear condition needs to change.

```
boolean isLeapYear = ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0) || (Year % 400 == 0));
```

Next your if(TwentyEight.contains(Month)) for this need to change to consider leap year.

```
if(TwentyEight.contains(Month) && !isLeapYear) {
        System.out.println(Month + " " + Year + " has " + DaysTwentyEight
                + " days in it.");
}
```